# zuul proxy slowness - RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient

Tags: httpclient, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

Firstly, I have only basic knowledge in java. I have some microservices and currently using zuul/eureka to proxy the services.

Noticed that when calling the microservice directly the throughput is 3 times faster than when called through zuul. So I'm wondering if my zuul configuration is wrong.

ab output:

Calling microservice directly:

```
Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   5.938 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      37750000 bytes
HTML transferred:       36190000 bytes
Requests per second:    1684.20 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       5.938 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.594 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          6208.84 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Calling through zuul:

```
Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   15.049 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      37990000 bytes
HTML transferred:       36190000 bytes
Requests per second:    664.52 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       15.049 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.505 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent
```

Zuul config:

```
server:
  port: 7001

zuul:
  #Services will be mapped under the /api URI
  prefix: /api
  sslHostnameValidationEnabled: false
  host:
    maxTotalConnections: 800
    maxPerRouteConnections: 200

endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false

eureka:
  instance:
      hostname: localhost
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

ribbon:
   eureka:
     enabled: true

spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-server
    id: zuul-server
```

---

Noticed that zuul takes a lot of CPU when compared to the microservice itself. So took a thread dump. And my suspicion is that RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient seems to keep instantiating.

---

Thread dump: https://1drv.ms/t/s!Atq1lsqOLA98mHjh0lSJHPJj5J_I

Answer (score 0):

The zuul.host.* properties you specified are only for zuul routes with "url" specified directly and do not apply to the serviceIds routes fetched from Eureka. [See here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2069#issuecomment-319163725). You may want to increase the ribbon level total HTTP connections and connections per host and rerun your test. Here is an example config -

```
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 30000
  ConnectTimeout: 1000
  MaxTotalHttpConnections: 1600
  MaxConnectionsPerHost: 800
```

In my tests with Zuul, I do remember seeing max-response times some of the requests were much higher than the zuul-bypassed direct to target requests, but the 95th and the 99th percentile were always comparable with approximately ~200ms difference with the direct requests to the target server.